# .NET WebService returns XML instead of JSON

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, web-services

I have .NET web service which supposed to return the result as JSON, but it returns it as XML? Here is my code.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/MyService")]
[ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<MyData> GetMyData(string dataFilter, string param)
    {
        if (dataFilter.ToLower() == "filterValue")
            return getData(param);
        return null;
    } 
}
public class MyData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    protected internal MyData() { } 
}
```

And here is the web.config

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<httpRuntime/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

**EDIT**
The web service is working fine only when passing digits in the parameters but it returns internal server error when passing characters inside the parameters. I got confused :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it may help you. Install **Newtonsoft.Json** package

**Code**

```
    public class HelloWorldData
    {
        public String Message;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void Select()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        HelloWorldData data = new HelloWorldData();
        string sql = "exec YOUR_SP_NAME";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BB_CONSTR"]);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        Context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
    }
```

Comment: Your code returns JSON format but it does not contain an object to parse it.  
{[{"Test":"200"}]} but i want it to return {"d":[{"Test":"200"}]}

Comment: can u share the screenshot of results.